# Characterizing continuous exponential functions for a topological field

Tags: general-topology, field-theory, exponentiation

Given a topological field $K$ that admits a non-trivial continuous exponential function $E$, must every non-trivial continuous exponential function $E'$ on $K$ be of the form $E'(x)=E(r\sigma (x))$ for some $r \in K$* and $\sigma \in Aut(K/\mathbb{Q})$?

If not, for which fields other than $\mathbb{R}$ is this condition met?

Thanks to Zev

Comment: Welcome to the site :)

Comment: What is an exponential function of any sort in this context?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_field

Answer (score 4):

It seems that as-stated, the answer is false. I'm not satisfied with the following counterexample, however, and I'll explain afterwards.

Take $K = \mathbb{C}$ and let $E(z) = e^z$ be the standard complex exponential. Take $E'(z) = \overline{e^z} = e^{\overline{z}}$, where $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$. Then $E'(z)$ is not of the form $E(r z)$, and yet is a perfectly fine homomorphism from the additive to the multiplicative groups of $\mathbb{C}$.

Here's why I'm not satisfied: you can take any automorphism of a field and cook up new exponentials by post-composition or pre-composition. In the case I mentioned, these two coincide.

This won't work in $\mathbb{R}$ because there are no nontrivial continuous automorphisms there. I would be interested in seeing an answer to a reformulation to this problem that reflected this.

Comment: okay, the problem has been reformulated. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a $p$-adic example to consider.  In ${\mathbf C}_p$ (the $p$-adic complex numbers) let $$D = \{x \in {\mathbf C}_p : |x|_p < (1/p)^{1/(p-1)}\},$$ which is the disc of convergence of the $p$-adic exponential series $\exp(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n/n!$. Then $\exp(D) = 1 + D$, and $1+D$ is a multiplicative subgroup of $1 + {\mathfrak m}_p$, where ${\mathfrak m}_p = \{x \in {\mathbf C}_p : |x|_p < 1\}$. The group $1 + {\mathfrak m}_p$ is *divisible*, so for any abelian group $G$ and subgroup $H$, any group homomorphism $f \colon H \rightarrow 1 + {\mathfrak m}_p$ extends to a group homomorphism $G \rightarrow 1 + {\mathfrak m}_p$. This extension from $H$ to $G$ is based on Zorn's lemma, and if you look at the proof you see that it involves gazillion choices along the way (if $[G:H] = \infty$).  So there's huge amount of flexibility in making the extension.

We will apply this to the additive group ${\mathbf C}_p$ and subgroup $D$: the homomorphism $\exp \colon D \rightarrow 1 + {\mathfrak m}_p$ extends to a homomorphism ${\mathbf C}_p \rightarrow 1 + {\mathfrak m}_p$ in many different ways. Since this extended homomorphism is the power series $\exp(x)$ on a neighborhood of $0$, the continuity of $\exp$ at $0$ implies the continuity of any extension to a homomorphism on ${\mathbf C}_p$. I haven't thought carefully about why you can't write all such extensions in terms of one of them using premultiplication, but it feels clear to me from the Zorn's lemma basis for making the extension that such a relation among all such extensions is not true.

Comment: If what you say is true, the situation is quite dire in $p$-adic fields. Is it true that any exponential for a $p$-adic field must be given by (an appropriate extension of) the power series form $\sum_n x^n/n!$?

Comment: Quite dire? As far as I know, such extensions of the $p$-adic exponential function have no applications to anything else, so their existence isn't really a big deal.

Comment: Let $B$ be a smaller disc around $0$ than $D$, so $B$ is an additive group, and extend $\exp \colon B \rightarrow 1 + {\mathfrak m}_p$ to a homomorphism ${\mathbf C}_p \rightarrow 1 + {\mathfrak m}_p$ by Zorn's lemma. This can be done without making it match $\exp$ on $D$, but the extension is still continuous since it's continuous on around $0$ (namely on $B$).

Comment: I'd like to hear whether or not this example is correct from somebody other than KCd. It seems very promising, but I am new to the p-adic numbers and not in a position to judge.

Comment: @JonathanAronson: Look in an algebra book for the section on divisible groups and read the proof of the theorem that for any subgroup $H$ of an abelian group $G$, any homomorphism $H \rightarrow \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is a divisible group, can be extended to a homomorphism $G \rightarrow \Delta$. It's a typical application of Zorn's lemma for extending the domain of a function (like the Hahn-Banach theorem too). The disc of convergence of the $p$-adic exponential function can be found in most books on $p$-adic analysis. If you want to use this for some purpose, try to understand it yourself.

Comment: Okay will do. I can appreciate that mentality. It was a question that came up in friendly conversation, so I'm not using it for anything. But the p-adic numbers do seem worth reading about and I can probably knock the group theory out quickly.

Comment: You don't need that the maximal disc of convergence of the exponential series on ${\mathbf C}_p$ is what I called $D$.  It's enough to just know the radius of convergence is positive, since any $p$-adic disc centered at 0 is an additive group (this is what I was writing about with more general discs $B$ in a comment above), and then Zorn's lemma can be used to extend a homomorphism from an open disc around 0 to all of ${\mathbf C}_p$. Showing $1 + {\mathfrak m}_p$, the open unit ball around 1 in ${\mathbf C}_p$, is divisible may be worth discussing with a colleague who knows $p$-adics.